# EOF error when running pifacedigital-scratch-handler

Tags: raspbian, scratch

I get this weird error when I am trying to run as per the instructions on this repo https://github.com/piface/pifacedigital-scratch-handler/blob/master/README.md

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ pifacedigital-scratch-handler 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pifacedigital-scratch-handler", line 17, in <module>
import pifacedigitalio as pfio
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

Comment: looking at only the error message it appears the file it is trying to read is either empty or corrupt. Try deleting the files and re-downloading them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is working now. 
Why I did - reinstalled python3
sudo apt-get remove python3
sudp apt-get install python3

and it worked !! I am not sure why. there seems to have been some clash between python2 and python3